# ¿Qué formato usar para exportar una base de datos en postgresql?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo una BD postgresql y quería saber cual sería la mejor extensión a la hora de realizar un backup ya que me salen varios formatos, ojo yo siempre uso el *Custom* para no complicarme pero quisiera saber si existe otra extensión con alguna ventaja distinta a la que uso siempre. Gracias...

Answer (score 1):

Es recomendable exportar tu base de datos en .sql.

Dicho archivo deberá contener todas las sentencias para crear tu base de datos, tus tablas, registros, relaciones, permisos...

Así se te va hacer más fácil importar tu información.

```
pg_dump -U postgres -f pg_mibd.sql mibd
```

O también:

```
pg_dump -U postgres mibd > pg_mibd.sql
```

Referencias:

https://www.linuxito.com/programacion/333-como-exportar-y-restaurar-bases-de-datos-postgres

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html